# ActionScript 3 constructor scope question

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, constructor

out of curiosity I decided to experiment with the following in a Flex 4 project:

```
public class MyGroup extends Group
{       
    public function MyGroup()
    {
        super();
        var myLabel:Label = new Label();
        myLabel.id = "myLabel";
        myLabel.text = "My label!";
        this.addElement(myLabel);
    } etc.
```

This custom component does what I'd expect; it looks like a label control with text="My label!".

Question: is there any way to reference the myLabel label control (e.g. to change the text) elsewhere in the project?

At the moment the only way I can get to the inner label control is by calling something like myGroup.getElementAt(0).

I realize that it would make more sense to have the label be a class variable -- I'm just wondering how this code works.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a public setter to change you text label:

```
public class MyGroup extends Group
{
    private var _label:Label=new Label();

    public function set label(value:String):void{
      _label.text=value;
    }

    public function MyGroup()
    {
        super();
        _label.id = "myLabel";
        label = "My label!";
        addElement(_label);
    }
.....
}

var myGroup:MyGroup=..
myGroup.label="Hello";
```

In your case since you are declaring your `var` `myLabel` inside a `function`, it 's scope will only apply inside this `function`

Answer (score 0):

In ActionScript, variables are named handles that you can pull on to get objects and data. Variables have something called **scope**, which specifies in what parts of the code the handle is valid.

When you create a variable inside a function, its scope is that function. That is, that particular named handle is only usable inside that function.

In your code, you create a handle called `myLabel`, and put a `Label` in it--let's call it `Label123`. Next you put `Label123` into the element list of `MyGroup`, which gives `MyGroup` a handle attached to `Label123`. Then the function ends, and the handle called `myLabel` is no longer usable. `Label123` still exists, because `MyGroup` has a handle to it.

If you create `myLabel` as a `private` or `protected` class variable, that handle will be usable from any function inside `MyGroup`. If you create it as a `public` class variable, it will be usable anywhere inside `MyGroup`, and also anywhere in the code you have an instance of `MyGroup`. (And if you create it as an `internal` class variable, it will be usable anywhere inside the package `MyGroup` is in.)